# how to display two line charts on a graphview in android getting the values from database?

Tags: android-graphview

how to display two line charts on a graphview in android getting the values from database?

here is my code

```
    gvp1=new GraphViewData[systolic.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<gvp1.length;i++)
        {
            gvp1[i]=new GraphViewData(Double.parseDouble(systolic.get(i).toString()), Double.parseDouble(diastolic.get(i).toString()));
        System.out.println("array avp1 is......."+Double.parseDouble(systolic.get(i).toString()));
        }

     LineGraphView graphView = new LineGraphView(
            this
            , "BP Graph"
    );


     graphView.addSeries(new GraphViewSeries(gvp1));

     System.out.println("in graphview......"+gvp1);

    /* 
     graphView.addSeries(new GraphViewSeries(new GraphViewData[] {

             new GraphViewData(1, 2.0d)
}));*/

    /*
     ViewHolder v = null;

     v = new ViewHolder();
     convertView=null;      
     */

     setContentView(graphView);
    // setContentView(R.layout.demo11);

     ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
     iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.graph_header);
        graphView.addView(iv);






}
```

this is how i am getting values from database to graph. but i want another line graph to be plotted on same scale.
any working code will be a great help..

Comment: just create a new GraphViewSeries and add it to the graphview. I do not really understand the problem. The best way is to try it in a small example with 2 series with hardcoded values. If it looks good to you, you can switch to get the data out of a database. I assume, that your data values are wrong and so you cannot see the second series...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call addSeries putting the other data of line graph.

See my implementation:

```
    GraphViewSeries line1Series = new GraphViewSeries("LINE ONE", new GraphViewSeriesStyle(Color.GREEN, 3), new GraphViewData[] { new GraphViewData(0, 0) }); // put an complete array
    GraphViewSeries line2Series = new GraphViewSeries("LINE TWO", new GraphViewSeriesStyle(Color.BLUE, 3), new GraphViewData[] { new GraphViewData(0, 0) }); // put an complete array

    graphView = new LineGraphView(this, "Graph with 2 lines");
    graphView.addSeries(line1Series);
    graphView.addSeries(line2Series);

    graphView.setShowLegend(true);
    graphView.setLegendAlign(LegendAlign.TOP);
    graphView.setGraphViewStyle(new GraphViewStyle(Color.DKGRAY, Color.DKGRAY, Color.LTGRAY));

    graphView.redrawAll();
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: I tried using same approach but graph view is not visible on screen.

Comment: @seema, this works fine, I tested too. Do you can post here your source code?

Comment: Issue was due to scroll view. My GraphView was in scroll view. Worked after removing scroll view.

Comment: I understand, thanks for your explanation. Should help others users.